# Tracer for OpenGl not showing any functions

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to follow along with [this article](http://www.curious-creature.com/2012/12/01/android-performance-case-study/) using Tracer for OpenGL. When I run this on my project I am able to capture a trace but I'm not seeing the functions that I expect. On the first frame I see:

[image]

On each subsequent frame I see only the `eglSwapBuffers` function. What am I doing wrong?

I've got the "Systrace (Graphics)" set in Developer Options on my device. I'm also setting the "Data Collection Options" correctly when I begin a trace.

Comment: What device are you using? I have seen devices that do not allow tracing with full release builds of the system. On those, you need a development build of the system/frameworks to use tracing. I don't know if that's intentional, or a bug. Not highly likely that this is your problem, but it's a possibility.

Comment: I'm testing on a Nexus 5 (API 23) and Samsung S5 (API 19).